# How do I use a declarative approach to optionally add an element to a list in R?

Tags: r, declarative

I'm dealing with json and have found using lists to be great so that I can use Map and whatnot. It's a more declarative approach, but I can't find a nice solution to optionally add a list element.

The nested list (ie "list(list(...))") style is necessary for creating the json that the api requires.

```
library(jsonlite)

# optionally add mydoc
mydoc <- NULL # mydoc <- 1

jelist <- list(
  JournalEntry = list(
    list(
      trxdate = '2019-01-01',
      docnum = mydoc,
      line = list(
        # 2 lines for 1 dr and 1 cr
        list(
          debitcredit = 'debit',
          accountref = 1
        ),
        list(
          debitcredit = 'credit',
          accountref = 2
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# it's added when I don't want it
toJSON(jelist,pretty = T,auto_unbox = T)
```

I can take it out afterward, but I'd like it to be a declarative approach instead of procedural. What if I want to embed it in a Map, or there's 50 to grok, remember, and maintain?

```
jelist$JournalEntry[[1]]$docnum <- NULL

# correct output    
toJSON(jelist,pretty = T,auto_unbox = T)
```

## quick simplify for the rest of the examples

Keeping this in might prevent false positive solutions that can handle simple lists but not nested lists.

```
linelist <- list(
  # 2 lines for 1 dr and 1 cr
  list(
    debitcredit = 'debit',
    accountref = 1
  ),
  list(
    debitcredit = 'credit',
    accountref = 2
  )
)
```

## things I've tried

### set as null, NA, logical(0)

```
jelist <- list(
  JournalEntry = list(
    list(
      trxdate = '2019-01-01',
      docnum = NULL, # or NA or logical(0)
      line = linelist
    )
  )
)
toJSON(jelist,pretty = T,auto_unbox = T)
```

### if stmt

```
jelist <- list(
  JournalEntry = list(
    list(
      trxdate = '2019-01-01',
      if(is.null(mydoc)){}else{docnum = mydoc}),
      line = linelist
    )
  )
toJSON(jelist,pretty = T,auto_unbox = T)
```

### Filter

I'd like the option to just declare it inline anyway if I want it removed or not. What if I actually do want to send a NULL as an update?

```
jelist <- list(
  JournalEntry = list(
    list(
      trxdate = '2019-01-01',
      docnum = mydoc,
      line = linelist
    )
  )
)
toJSON(Filter(Negate(is.null),jelist),pretty = T,auto_unbox = T)
```

### messing with c, list, etc.

```
jelist <- list(
  JournalEntry = list(
    list(
      trxdate = '2019-01-01',
      as.list(c(docnum = NULL)),
      line = linelist
    )
  )
)
toJSON(jelist,pretty = T,auto_unbox = T)
```

I tried unlist/relist, but I'm not too familiar with using those. Again, hoping I can have it optional inline.
Tried changing lists around to using c() and as.list() with some promising things but not success. Somehow c() renames my 2 Lines with Line1 and Line2.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`plyr::compact` will remove `NULL` from lists. By default, it operates on an already-constructed list. To be able to use it declaratively, you need to [lift its domain](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/lift.html) from list to dots.

```
mylist <- purrr::lift_ld( plyr::compact )

## For example,
mylist( a=1, b=NULL, c=3 )
# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $c
# [1] 3
```

Now simply replace every call to `list()` with a call to the newly defined `mylist`:

```
jelist <- mylist(
  JournalEntry = mylist(
    mylist(
      trxdate = '2019-01-01',
      docnum = mydoc,
      line = mylist(
        # 2 lines for 1 dr and 1 cr
        mylist(
          debitcredit = 'debit',
          accountref = 1
        ),
        mylist(
          debitcredit = 'credit',
          accountref = 2
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

toJSON(jelist, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)   ## Works as desired
```